# How to get the Value in the labels for the 2 independent buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have `two buttons` with a `single label` like the below. The two buttons were **independent**.

```
<label for="buttons" class ="val">0</label>
      <input class="btn btn-primary button1" type="button" value="button1" onclick="changeLabel()">
      <input class="btn btn-primary button2" type="button" value="button2">
```

When I click the button1 `1sttime`, the Value in the label should be `1`, for the 2nd time, the value in the label should be `2` and for the `3rd time`, the value in the label should be `3`. When I click the `button1` for the `4th time`, the value should again go back to `0`. Like 0,1,2,3,0,1.....

The same should be the case for the `button2` too. But, If i press the `button1` `2times`. Then the Value in the label should be `2`.At the same time, if I press the `button2` for `3times`  the value in the label should change to `3` immediately.

Both the buttons, should be **independent**. The Values should be different for each buttons when they were clicked.

```
(".button1").click(function(){
     var value = $('.val').html(parseInt($('.val').html())+1);
});

$(".button2").click(function(){
     $('.val').html(parseInt($('.val').html())+1);
});
```

I couldn't do so. The value should return to `0` after clicking the buttons `3 times`.
here is my codepen, https://codepen.io/Davi9/pen/LYLqWKx

could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would reset the value to 0

Comment: @Davi this occurs because you only have '+1', it will always add a 1 whenever whichever button is pressed. There's many ways this could be done, you can even create an array from 0 to 3 and loop through those (+1), and whenever it reaches the full array length, just make it start over. Not the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the counter to `0` when it reach `3`, then try this:

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
  var v = +$(".val").html();
  $(".val").html(v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".button1").click(function() {
  var v = +$(".val").html();
  $(".val").html(v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
});

$(".button2").click(function() {
  var v = +$(".val").html();
  $(".val").html(v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <br />
        <label for="buttons" class="val">0</label>
        <br />
        <input class="btn btn-primary button1" type="button" value="button1">
        <input class="btn btn-primary button2" type="button" value="button2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the label, if its greater than 3, set it to zero, somthing like

```
(".button1").click(function(){
   incr();
});

$(".button2").click(function(){
   incr();
});

function incr() {
  var val = parseInt($('.val').html());
  val=val+1;
  if(val > 3)
    val = 0;
  $('.val').html(val);
}
```